# Why can't I call meta methods on Routine::WrapHandle?

Tags: raku

This is a continuing question from my previous one [Why is Perl 6's unwrap method a method of Routine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43793769/2766176), but mostly unrelated.

The `wrap` method is documented to return "an instance of a private class called WrapHandle. Besides that being odd for leaking a class that's private, it's not actually the name of the thing that comes back. The class is actually `Routine::WrapHandle`:

```
$ perl6
> sub f() { say 'f was called' }
sub f () { #`(Sub|140397740886648) ... }
> my $wrap-handle = &f.wrap({ say 'before'; callsame; say 'after' });
Routine::WrapHandle.new
```

But here's the question. I wanted to call `.^methods` on `Routine::WrapHandle`. That doesn't work:

```
> Routine::WrapHandle.^methods
Could not find symbol '&WrapHandle'
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

This is the same as trying it on an undefined class name:

```
> Foo::Baz.^methods
Could not find symbol '&Baz'
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

I can call meta methods on the instance though:

```
> $wrap-handle.^methods
(restore)
> $wrap-handle.^name
Routine::WrapHandle
```

What's going on there?

Comment: It's a [lexical class](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?&q=WrapHandle&type=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of `Routine::WrapHandle` looks something like this:

```
my class Routine {
    method wrap(&wrapper) {
        my class WrapHandle { ... }
        ...
    }
}
```

We can ignore the surrounding method; the important bit is that we're dealing with a lexical inner class defined within an outer class. Simplifying some more, we arrive at the following pattern:

```
package Foo {
    my class Bar {}
    say Bar.^name; #=> Foo::Bar
}

say try Foo::Bar; #=> Nil
```

The fully qualified name of the inner class will include the name of the enclosing package, but due to the explicit `my` (instead of the implicit `our`), the class will not be installed as a package variable and the lookup at file scope fails.